# How can I save messages publishing from a ROS package into a variable?

Tags: ros, python

I am using darknet_ros_3d package and writing a subscriber. So far, I have followed the code given as under:

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from darknet_ros_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxes
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from std_msgs.msg import String


def callback(data):
    for box in data.bounding_boxes:
        rospy.loginfo(
            "Xmin: {}, Xmax: {} Ymin: {}, Ymax: {}".format(
                box.xmin, box.xmax, box.ymin, box.ymax
            )
        )


def main():
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber('/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes', BoundingBoxes , callback)
        rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try :
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

How can I save the values coming from Xmin: {}, Ymin: {}, etc. into the variables for the later usage?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use **classes** and save the data into class variables. Try this:

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from darknet_ros_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxes
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from std_msgs.msg import String


class darknet_ros_3d:

  def __init__(self):
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes', BoundingBoxes , self.callback)

  def callback(self, data):
    for box in data.bounding_boxes:
      rospy.loginfo(
        "Xmin: {}, Xmax: {} Ymin: {}, Ymax: {}".format(
        box.xmin, box.xmax, box.ymin, box.ymax)
        )
    # save data into variables
    self.Xmin = box.xmin
    self.Xmax = box.xmax
    self.Ymin = box.ymin
    self.Ymax = box.ymax


if __name__ == '__main__':
  darknet_ros_3d()
  try:
    rospy.spin()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Shutting down")
```

You can now use these variables by calling self.(variable) in other parts of your code as long as it is referenced within the class

Comment: Thanks for the response @Akhil Kurup. I am getting the following error when I called self.Xmin: "AttributeError: darknet_ros_3d instance has no attribute 'Xmin' ".

Comment: Since the `__init__()` function doesn't initialise the `Xmin` attribute, you will get this error if you try to access the attribute before the `callback()` is called for the first time. If this is likely, you should either initialise the attributes in the `__init__()` function, or check if the object has the attribute before attempting to access it using the `hasattr()` function.

Comment: Yes, as Mark has suggested, if you try to access self.(variable) before any value has been set, you will get this error. You could either set self.Xmin = 0.0 in the init or at the place you are trying to access the value, check if these values exist.

Comment: I have now initialized self.Xmin = 0 and now the error is removed. But I need to ask that will the self.Xmin update after its initial value through the callback function? The code is given as under: `def __init__(self):
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    self.Xmin = 0
    rospy.Subscriber('/darknet_ros_3d/bounding_boxes', BoundingBoxes3d, self.callback)
    pose = [self.Xmin, 0.15, 0.3, 0.0, 3.14, 3.14] `

Comment: self.Xmin will update every time the callback function is called. The __init__ function is only executed once in the beginning. So you might want to populate the pose elsewhere where you want to use it.